How to make ListView width be equal to the widest cell?
I need to make ListView just enough to show the widest cell (without cutting) but no more. For example, if there are three labels with width 100px, 200px, 300px then ListView width must be 300px.
I tried the following code, but it didn't work:
public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "Short item",
            "A bit longer item",
            "This is a much longer item that needs more space"
        );

        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(items);

        ListCell<String> tempCell = new ListCell<>();
        double maxWidth = 0;
        for (String item : items) {
            tempCell.setText(item);
            double cellWidth = tempCell.prefWidth(-1);
            if (cellWidth > maxWidth) {
                maxWidth = cellWidth;
            }
        }

        listView.setPrefWidth(maxWidth);
        var tabPane = new TabPane(new Tab("Test"));
        HBox.setHgrow(tabPane, Priority.ALWAYS);
        var root = new HBox(listView, tabPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("ListView Width Example");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

Could anyone say how to do it?

I do not work with JavaFX, but I guess setting the preferred width of your listview is counterproductive. Just add it to a container that uses a suitable layout and the listview should do the needful.

Duplicate question: How to make ListView width fit width of its cells.  Unfortunately the current upvoted answer there looks incorrect to me.

Proposed Kotlin based solution (I didn't try it).

Old blog post: Setting the preferred width of a ListView to fit its items in JavaFX.  I didn't try it, and it is complex, but looks the most promising to me.  But do consider if you need this functionality, as following the advice of @queeg might suffice instead.

I would suggest using Text and add something like 25 to the width.
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "Short item",
            "A bit longer item",
            "This is a much longer item that needs more space"
        );

        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(items);

        
        double maxWidth = 0;
        for (String item : items) {
            Text text = new Text(item);
            double cellWidth = text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() + 25;
            if (cellWidth > maxWidth) {
                maxWidth = cellWidth;
            }
        }

        listView.setPrefWidth(maxWidth);
        var tabPane = new TabPane(new Tab("Test"));
        HBox.setHgrow(tabPane, Priority.ALWAYS);
        var root = new HBox(listView, tabPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("ListView Width Example");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}


Idea from How to calculate the pixel width of a String in JavaFX?

+1 for the suggestion of @queeg and the solution of @SedJ601. While they both work in their aspects, if you want the solution to be more dynamic, you can try the below solution. (pretty much the kind of principle you are trying with).
You need to set the created temp cell under the same parent of actual cells, so that the CSS inhertance can be applied effectively (if any) and the calculations will be correct irrespective of the styling of the cells.
Note: This is the same/similar logic used in JavaFX's TableColumnHeader.java -> resizeColumnToFitContent method.

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListViewWidthExample extends Application {

    public static final String CSS = "data:text/css," +
            """
                    .list-cell .text{
                         -fx-font-weight: bold;
                         -fx-font-size: 14px;
                     }
                            """;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "Short item",
                "A bit longer item",
                "This is a much longer item that needs more space"
        );

        var tabPane = new TabPane(new Tab("Test"));
        HBox.setHgrow(tabPane, Priority.ALWAYS);
        var root = new HBox(buildListView(items), tabPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 200);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(CSS);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("ListView Width Example");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private ListView<String> buildListView(ObservableList<String> items) {
        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(items) {
            boolean computed = false;

            @Override
            protected void layoutChildren() {
                super.layoutChildren();
                if (!computed) {
                    ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<>();
                    cell.updateListView(this);

                    // All cells are grouped in sheet in VirtualFlow
                    Group sheet = (Group) lookup(".sheet");
                    sheet.getChildren().add(cell);
                    double maxWidth = 0;
                    for (int row = 0; row < items.size(); row++) {
                        cell.updateIndex(row);
                        cell.setText(items.get(row));
                        cell.applyCss();
                        maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, cell.prefWidth(-1));
                    }
                    setPrefWidth(maxWidth + snappedLeftInset() + snappedRightInset());

                    // Dispose of the cell
                    sheet.getChildren().remove(cell);
                    cell.updateIndex(-1);

                    // We do this only once... if you want to be dynamic if items are added/removed, then remove this flag to compute always.
                    computed = true;
                }
            }
        };
        return listView;
    }
}

